# guardar array de objetos Schema mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose, schema

Cuando realizo un post con la informacion en postman no se carga la informacion completa, quisiera saber si la forma en la que he realizado mi schema es la correcta o donde podria estar el fallo ya que toda la informacion se carga correctamente menos los array.

Este es el SCHEMA de datos de mongoose que tengo en mi codigo, no se si deberia hacerlo asi ya que otras veces he implementado este formato y me ha funcionado bien, o si deberia hacer los 2 schemas por separado en otro file y exportarlos como podulos y asociarlos por id aunque esa no es la manera que quisiera hacerlo por ahi es la correcta y por eso no me esta funcionando, lo raro es que si la misma informacion que envio por post en postman la ingreso en mongo atlas por el explorador me toma los datos tal cual los ingreso como deberia hacerlo, pero claro no podra hacer post desde mi frontend luego si me fallan los metodos post

```
import { model, Schema } from "mongoose";

const lessonSchema = new Schema({
    lessonName: String,
    lessonTime: Number
});

const moduleSchema = new Schema({
    moduleName: String,
    lesson: [lessonSchema]
});

const coursesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    modules: [moduleSchema],
    duration: Number,
    imgUrl: String,
    type: String,
    description: String,
    prominent: Boolean
}, 
{
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

const Courses = model('Courses', coursesSchema);

export default Courses;
```

Asi es como se guardan los datos en mongodb una vez que realizo la peticion post

```
{
    "message": "Course created successfully",
    "data": {
        "name": "JavaScript",
        "modules": [
            {
                "lesson": [
                    {}
                ]
            }
        ],
        "duration": 20,
        "imgUrl": "https://",
        "type": "Intermedio",
        "description": "CURSO PARA BASES DE JS",
        "prominent": false
    }
}
```

METODO POST PARA REALIZAR LA PETICION EN POSTMAN DE COMO ENVIO LOS DATOS

```
{
    "name": "JavaScript",
    "modules": [
        {
            "moduleName": "Inicio",
            "lesson": [
                {"lessonName": "sesion 1", "lessonTime": 2},
                {"lessonName": "sesion 2", "lessonTime": 3},
                {"lessonName": "sesion 3", "lessonTime": 5}
            ]
        },
        {
            "moduleName": "Fin",
            "lesson": [
                {"lessonName": "sesion 4", "lessonTime": 1},
                {"lessonName": "sesion 5", "lessonTime": 4},
                {"lessonName": "sesion 6", "lessonTime": 7}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "duration": 20,
    "imgUrl": "https://",
    "type": "Intermedio",
    "description": "CURSO PARA BASES DE JS",
    "prominent": false
}
```